# show and hide div Android style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animate.css

i am trying to create html app without any framework. i want add some animation for changing one div to another div. so then it will be feel like better then just jump one div another div. for animation using animate.css. now problem is when i continuously next and back sometime animation not work and div not. i found why it is but can not fix. it is because of class not add and remove properly by click.

Please check my example. when i click **NEXT**  it's show another div then when i click **Create an Account** it's show another div then when i click **BACK** it is back signup page. this is animation working but again when i click **Create an Account** then div move (login page) away but another div (signup page) not showing.

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/u78adoto/1/

**Html**

```
<div class="overlaycontent">
<!--   Choose country area  -->
<div class="country-selector">
<h4>Choose Country</h4>
<form>
<input id="bangaldesh" type="radio" name="country" value="bangaldesh" />
<label class="country-label bd" for="bangaldesh"></label>
<input id="malaysia" type="radio" name="country" value="malaysia" />
<label class="country-label my" for="malaysia"></label></form>
<div class="next-btn"><a href="#">Next</a></div>
</div>



  <div class="userinput hidepanel">
 <div class="section country-selectd"> <img src="images/flag-bangladesh.png" alt=""/></div>

 <!-- sign in area-->
 <div class="section signin-panel">
<form action="call-log.html">
      <div class="inputarea user">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
      </div>
      <div class="inputarea password">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="sbtn btn-login" formaction="call-log.html" value="login">
      <input type="submit" class="sbtn btn-create" formaction="call-log.html" value="Create an Account" id="creatbtn">
      <input type="submit" class="sbtn btn-more" formaction="call-log.html" value="More">
    </form>
</div>

    <!-- sign up area-->
<div class="section signup-panel hidepanel">
<div class="inputarea phone"><input type="tel" placeholder="Your Telephone Number"></div>
<div class="inputarea user"><input type="text" placeholder="User Name"></div>
<div class="inputarea password"><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
<div class="inputarea password"><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
<input type="submit" class="sbtn btn-login" formaction="call-log.html" value="Sign Up">
      <input type="submit" class="sbtn" value="Back" id="backbtn">
  </div>


</div>

</div>
```

**Js**

```
$(".next-btn a").click(function(){
            $('.country-selector').addClass('animated slideOutLeft');
            $('.userinput').addClass('animated slideInRight').show();
                return false;
            });

    $(".btn-create").click(function(){
            $('.signin-panel').addClass('animated slideOutLeft');
            $('.signup-panel').addClass('animated slideInRight').removeClass('hidepanel slideOutLeft').show();
                return false;
            });



    $("#backbtn").click(function(){
            $('.signup-panel').addClass('animated slideOutRight').removeClass('slideOutLeft');
            $('.signin-panel').addClass('animated slideInLeft').removeClass('hidepanel slideOutLeft');
                return false;
            });
```

i am not sure my JavaScript or slideing way is good or bad but if you guys know any other solution for slide one div to another and feel that Android page animation please advice.

may be without animate.css also possible just position transition with css animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i make it happen. manually but it would if there any script like that. may be some kind of slider code will work. updated code here

```
> https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/u78adoto/3/
```

Comment: You should add your code in your answer. Just linking isn't good enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you still have the classes on the elements when you are going through things. I would remove the classes on the elements when the animations are finished.

However if you do this, it will revert to the old styles without the classes `animated slideXX` So I would suggest removing the unused HTML after the animations are finished. This is what using a framework will give you.

Anyway you have already identified this.

So what you were after, even though is a poor selector and even poor solution it might help you:

```
function removeClasses (){
    var selectors = '.slideOutLeft, .animated, .slideInRight';
    $().removeClass(selectors );
}

$(".next-btn a").click(function(){
   removeClasses ();
   $('.country-selector').addClass('animated slideOutLeft');
   $('.userinput').addClass('animated slideInRight').show();
   return false;
});

$(".btn-create").click(function(){
   removeClasses ();
   $('.signin-panel').addClass('animated slideOutLeft');
   $('.signup-panel').addClass('animated slideInRight').removeClass('hidepanel slideOutLeft').show();
   return false;
});

$("#backbtn").click(function(){
   removeClasses ();
   $('.signup-panel').addClass('animated slideOutRight').removeClass('slideOutLeft');
   $('.signin-panel').addClass('animated slideInLeft').removeClass('hidepanel slideOutLeft');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. i tried with your code but it not really work. update code here https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/u78adoto/2/